# Why does the first gets() not work in this code?

Tags: c++

I have tried this code (in multiple programs) using dev c++ and code::Blocks but the first gets() command will never get executed when followed by a cin>>

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i;
char c[10], d[10];
cout<<"Enter int ";
cin>>i;
cout<<"Enter string ";
gets(c); // this is where things act all possessed
cout<<"Enter 2nd string ";
gets(d);
cout<<i<<endl<<c<<endl<<d;
return 0;
}
```

Please help me out

**What I have tried:**

I have tried taking variable i as char, then taking the input using only gets()'s, which works flawlessly
but then i strictly need to take it as an integer, in some programs, to be able to do stuff like increment/decrement/whatever

Comment: Don't ever use `gets`, it's a relic from old C days. It's broken function, that is very prone to buffer overflows. If you were using C, I would recommend that you use `fgets` instead. But since you are using C++, I think you have to use `cin` with `std::string` instead of plain `char` strings.

Comment: @user694733 OP's problem is not about unsafety of gets, but about misunderstanding of how it works. He'll get same problem with cin.getLine() or whatever else

Comment: @DenisSheremet Hence comment, and not an answer. But it's still error to use `gets` anyway, since it's pretty crap function.

Answer (score 1):

Gets is not 'not getting executed', but returns an empty string. This happens because `cin` leaves cursor at line where it finished reading. You should read this line with any possible way, for example read it with same `gets` to some buffer